# Simpler way to enable/disable voltage regulator using DC jack shunt as a switch?

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, dc

I am wanting to know if there is a simpler way to enable/disable a switching voltage regulator I'm using. The voltage regulator's datasheet says to pull the EN pin to GND to turn it off, and let it float to turn it on.

The DC jack is being used as the on/off switch in this product. The middle pin is the shunt, and is normally contacting the sleeve/GND when the charger isn't plugged in. When the charger is plugged into the jack, the shunt disconnects from the sleeve, and the NPN transistor base is pulled high through a resistor and turns on, turning off the voltage regulator.

When the charger is unplugged, the shunt pin connects back to GND, pulling the NPN's base to GND and turning the voltage regulator on.

I feel like I've overlooked something and there is a more simple way? Thank you for your help.

The product, charger, and jack are center pin positive.

VCC is a 12V battery.

Schematic:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking for a regulator that has the behavior you desire?

Comment: I know there are regulators that you pull up high to turn them off, but the regulator I have chosen has been working perfectly in my design and I don't really want to change it. It is inexpensive and has a low count BOM.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but have you confirmed with the datasheet that EN is in a well-defined state when Q1 is off?

Comment: @replete yes, and in the real world confirmed on my test PCB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler than what you have? Without changing the regulator? No. A NPN plus resistor is as simple as you can get. The other option would be a voltage comparator, and a diode as a reverse protection and isolating node when the charger is connected. Which your battery may not like.

Comment: I was looking for a pre-biased transistor to reduce the component count, but that wouldn't work as they don't give you a pin after the base resistor.

Comment: Have you seen any pre-biased transistors what I'm looking for?

Comment: There are transistors with built in base resistors, but you want a pull-up and a pull-down. I doubt it's cheaper than an individual resistor.

Comment: Would this work? http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/DTC143E-D-278514.pdf I have some on hand. There isn't a pin at the two resistors junction though; would that matter?

Comment: No. If you connect the base to VCC, then you have no strong pull-up  down when the shunt is connected. It would only turn off  when vcc goes below 1.2 volts or so.

Comment: So I would need to find a pre-biased transistor that offers a pin at the two resistor junctions to solve that? The jack's shunt would connect to that junction.

Comment: How about this one, with R2 being infinite/not installed http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/DTC114T-D-462194.pdf

Comment: If you can find an optocoupler with a built in led resistor that would be a four pin single part solution. Make sure it's sized for 12V operation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55876/discussion-between-aviatorken89-and-passerby).

Answer (score 2):

It's not 103% obvious whether the break jack acts as an on/off switch to other components as well but, if not.

You could reverse the jack polarity **if** that's acceptable.
The break contact jack is now in the +ve lead.
See diagram below.
[image]